# Boolean Alegebra De morgans rule 2

Tags: boolean-algebra

hi i am told to perform a simplification using demorgans rule 2.

Here is the question

' = Equals Not

B . (C + B')'

I got

B' + (C' + B'')           then

B' + (C' + B)  Now i dont know where to go from here. Could you guys please help. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you've taken the negation of the expression you want. Consider:

B . (C + B')'

((B . (C + B')')')'

(B' + (C + B')'')'

(B' + (C + B'))'

...which doesn't look like a simplification at all. So, we simply negate the inner "or":

B . (C' . B'')

B . (C' . B)

Comment: Im sorry ken im finding it hard to understand, If you dont mind Could you display it the way i have written , its the way ive been taught. Im very sorry but ive been on this question for about 4-5 hours now and its really frustrating

Comment: Sure thing. Edited.

Comment: Ken are you able to attach pics to a message? or is there a private message function so i can hand write the equation

Comment: I've edited again to remove all the formal logic symbols.

Comment: So B. (C+B') ' becomes B. (C'.B) ? im sorry about this its so difficult for me

Answer (score 0):

$$B • \overline{ (C + \overline {B})}$$

Take DeMorgan's on second term.  Remove complement, change operator (which you did not do) and complement terms.

$$B • (\overline {C} • \overline {\overline {B}})$$
$$B • \overline {C} • B$$

$ X•X = X $, which means:

$$B • \overline {C}$$